# Keycloak in Openshift, being called from a pod

Tags: keycloak, openshift-origin

I have a tricky question about Keycloak and Openshift.

I have set up a Keycloak server in an Openshift Origin installation, and set up an external route for it.

I also have set up a nodejs app in the same Openshift Origin, and I'm trying to access the Keycloak server using it's external route DNS.

The Keycloak server is available externally at identity.myapp.com
My app is available externally at app.myapp.com

But when my nodejs app tries to retrieve the token with the Token Endpoint it gets stuck with a `No route to Host` error.

When I get into the nodejs app pod and ping the external DNS name, it responds properly, but when I try a `wget` command on it I also get a `No route to Host` error.

Here's the log of my test :

```
sh-4.2$ ping identity.myapp.com  
PING identity.myapp.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) 56(84) bytes of data. 
64 bytes from xxx (xx.xx.xx.xx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.236 ms
64 bytes from xxx (xx.xx.xx.xx): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.170 ms 
--- identity.myapp.com ping statistics --- 
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms 
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.170/0.203/0.236/0.033 ms  
sh-4.2$ wget https://identity.myapp.com 
--2017-06-28 20:29:29--  https://identity.myapp.com/
Resolving identity.myapp.com (identity.myapp.com)... xx.xx.xx.xx  
Connecting to identity.myapp.com (identity.myapp.com)|xx.xx.xx.xx|:443... failed: No route to host.
```

I can't call the Keycloak server using it's internal DNS name, it's set up to deliver tokens with it's external issuer DNS name and any call to it with another name results to an `Invalid token issuer` error (I have opened a ticket on the github of the library I'm using, you can find it [here](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client/issues/38#issuecomment-311774873)

My ultimate solution would be to externalize the Keycloak server, but I would lose all the benefits offered by Openshift...

What can I do to access the Keycloak server using it's external DNS name in `HTTPS` from my app pod?

Comment: Ended up putting the keycloak server outside of my Openshift infrastructure. If somebody comes up with a working solution I'd still be happy to try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be related to the router or with DNS.  Have you tried setting an external DNS provider for your nodejs app?

I assume you have a [route](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/dev_guide/routes.html) set up as well?

Comment: I haven't tried setting an external DNS provider for the nodejs app. Is it a good thing to do ? And also, as I said, I have set up a route for the Keycloak server, and the route also works. I can access the Keycloak server from my browser. But I need this secure route to work from the inside too (from my nodejs app's pod). I tried accessing Keycloak using it's service name (it works), but I break the OpenID workflow doing so, and Keycloak refuses to give my app the token it needs to authenticate the user.

Comment: Actually, it was the DNS configuration, along with the router. The FQDN showed the public IP of the router, but for a reason I haven't found the pod couldn't access that IP from within the cluster. I ended up configuring a fake DNS server that served the internal IP of the node containing the router pod. Thanks (exactly 2 years later...)